# How do I compare furnace models?

Tags: hvac, heating, furnace

I need a new furnace, and I have quotes from two companies, for three different brands of furnace, Carrier, Trane, and Lennox. Both companies have provided the model numbers of the units they would install.

I understand how to compare efficiencies, and some of the features, such as variable speed fans and dual stage burners. Each of the manufacturers offers basically the same models, such as 80% single stage, 95% single stage, 80% dual stage variable, 95% dual stage variable. Comparable models are are similar in price, within 5-8%.

How can I compare the models to determine which is the best fit for me?

Comment: Do you want to compare and choose based on the efficiency levels, or are you asking if Trane is better than Carrier and Lennox?  The brand choice seems "highly opinion based" as the mods say.  The efficiency is going to be a tradeoff between initial investment and operating costs with very quickly diminishing returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is best to purchase a level of unit that meets the needs of the home.  80% single stage is good for basic heat where the fuel is not too expensive and the climate is not too cold.  More sophisticated technology has higher initial costs and repair costs, so it is not advantageous to go up the efficiency scale unless justified by the fuel savings.  The quiet operation and more even heat distribution that comes with a variable speed 2 stage unit is loved by some homeowners, but again that adds complexity and cost.  Also, 2 stage variable speed does not save much in operating costs.  If one is not sensitive to cost and one wants to buy something fancy to show to the neighbors, I see no fault in that.

I would also say that correct sizing of the unit, correct installation, and a reliable contractor are all much more important than brand.